# Errors and issues when install G++ on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, system-installation, sudo, g++

Trying to install g++ when I run into this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++
[sudo] password for eisha: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: g++-9 (>= 9.3.0-3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is the output of the command `$ apt policy g++`:

```
$ apt policy g++
g++:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Here is the output of the command `$ apt policy g++-9`:

```
$ apt policy g++-9
g++-9:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  Version table:
     9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     9.3.0-10ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

yes i did try :  `sudo apt install build-essential` and the output is lke this :

```
sudo apt install build-essential
[sudo] password for eisha: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                            libc-dev
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:9.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And yes i also tried `sudo apt update`
i got a very long output, and the ending lines were:

```
Last modification reported: Wed, 26 Jan 2022 19:25:00 +0000
   Release file created at: Wed, 26 Jan 2022 16:17:36 +0000
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.xz  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133548/discussion-on-question-by-eisha-latif-i-was-installing-g-in-ubuntu-but-unfor).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: Downgrade `libc6` to `libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2` and install `build-essential`.

You don't have the required repositories enabled. Moreover, there are broken versions of the packages.

By running `apt-cache policy g++` on Ubuntu 20.04, I get:

```
g++:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://mirrors.my mirror.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

So, you've to enable the `main` repository.
Run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main && sudo apt update
```

After enabling the `main` repository. Install the correct version of `libc6`:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```

DON'T run `apt upgrade`.

Now, update and do clean:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt -f install
```

Now, install the meta-package, `build-essential` to install `g++`:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude -f install build-essential
```

If the above didn't work, then try restoring the default repositories and using `aptitude` to install build-essential:

```
sudo mkdir ~/answer && cd ~/answer/ && sudo wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170/raw/3822ba49241e6fd851ca1c1cbcc4d7e87382f484/sources.list && sudo sed -i "s/focal/$(lsb_release -c -s)/" ~/answer/sources.list && sudo mv ~/answer/sources.list /etc/apt/ && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade  && sudo rm -rf ~/answer
sudo aptitude -f install build-essential
```

**Still didn't work**?

Edit your question to include:

- `sudo apt install libc6-dev`
- `sudo apt update`
- `apt-cache policy libc6`
- `apt-cache policy libc-dev`

Ping me after adding these details ;)

Comment: Oh is it because of the incorrect `libc6` version?

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes.

Comment: Maybe restoring the default repositories (we already have some questions for that) and then fully updating the system would fix the issue?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I'm not sure about that (I've already mentioned it in my answer though). But the main problem is the incorrect version of libc.

Answer (score 0):

[As per this documentation try the following](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-g-the-c-compiler-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-linux):

First, update the package index, `sudo apt update`.

The recommended way to install the C++ compiler on Ubuntu 20.04 is by installation of the entire development package `build-essential`.

To install run the following:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential
```

Then to check if it was successfully installed run:

```
$ g++ --version
```

You should get an output similar to below:

```
$ g++ --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.2.1-17ubuntu1) 9.2.1 20191102
```

Comment: Completely wrong answer. If OP can't install `g++` then how will they install `build-essential`? Its obvious, `build-essential` depends on `g++` and installing `g++` is throwing errors!